# NSDateFormatter - day of week different on simulator vs hardware

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to determine the current day of the week in my app. To do this I have:

```
NSDateFormatter* dayDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dayDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"e"];
int todayDayNum = [[dayDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
[dayDateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"%d", todayDayNum);
```

Today is currently a Thursday for me, and on my iPhone I am getting the value `4` as the result. However, on the simulator I get `5`.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I have tried both `c` and `e` as the format string. I have also double checked that the date/time is correct (and the same) on both the simulator and the device.

**Edit**: I've changed my code to the following, which seems to work consistently now (I get `5` for both my device and the simulator. I am guessing that this is because my device is using some other calendar?

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger todayDayNum = [weekdayComponents weekday];
NSLog(@"%d", todayDayNum);
```

Comment: yeah, firstDay of week in different calendar may be not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to play with 
[gregorian setFirstWeekday:1]; // Sunday == 1, Saturday == 7 etc

or locale - [gregorian setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; 
because it influenced too